# Creating 3D polyline just below another polyline using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, geology, create

I have a geological setting where I would like to add a lithology to an existing map. I already have the 3D polylines from my geological map and the DEM I now want to add another polyline between two outcrops that occurs like 20 m below one polyline and follows the topography.

Picture one shows the 3D model and two the 2D one. The black line is what i would like to create automated with ArcGIS Desktop.

Anyone an idea how to do that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about some kind of 3D contour line that will be below 20m of one of your polyline and follows the topography of your area ?

Comment: yeah that sounds exactly like i would like to have it

Comment: @Polygeo I am attempting to post solution. It won't let me add picture to it. Tried Chrome and Internet Explorer. Same result.

Comment: If you like to add a 3D contour line you can simply create contours between the two 3D polylines using the DEM and select your desire 20 m contour then interpolate it on the DEM surface and copy it to your 3D polyline layer.

Comment: @SaadAsif it's not that easy the problem is that the other lines are not leven and cut through some contour lines

Comment: ok thats a lot i will try this later today

Comment: @FelixIP I came across your comment by chance.  How big is the image that you are trying to add?  Since you put a smaller one in your answer, I'm guessing you may be hitting an SE rather than GIS SE limit and [meta.se] may be the place to research it.

Comment: @PolyGeo (correct this time, sorry) 103,269 bytes exported from 15 cm *15 cm layout at 72 dpi resolution, png.

Comment: @FelixIP Your first ping did not alert me because I had not been active on the post until my first comment.  This is what I found on imgur size limits: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308507/image-size-limit-why-it-is-set-to-2-mb - it may or may not apply.  In any event I think [meta.se] will be the place to research this limit.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it works with tiny images (Bad news), anyway.
If you line climbs gently along contours, like kerb below does:

[image]

Try this after splitting it into smaller bits:

```
arcpy.InterpolateShape_3d("dem", "splits", "C:/SCRATCH/splits3d.shp")
arcpy.AddZInformation_3d("splits3d", "Z_MEAN")
arcpy.gp.EucAllocation_sa("splits3d", "C:/SCRATCH/ea", "", "", "2", "FID")
arcpy.AddJoin_management("ea", "VALUE", "splits3d", "FID")
arcpy.gp.Lookup_sa("ea", "splits3d.Z_Mean", "C:/SCRATCH/SURFACE")
arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa('Con("dem"  <=  "SURFACE" - 3,1)', "C:/SCRATCH/one")
```

This will produce something very similar to what you want:

[image]

Comment: sry for the late answer. Is there any way you could tell me the normal commands i can you. I have never worked with python.

Comment: These are normal commands, tools.